# Resolving typescript directory aliases to relative paths

Tags: typescript, gulp

I'm just starting up with typescript and trying to get module resolution working. My issue is pretty simple (I think), but I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong with my `tsconfig.json`.

If I have a folder structure of:

```
+ release
    + definitions
    + js
        > a.js
        > main.js
+ src
    > main.ts
    > a.ts
```

Using gulp, I'm doing [incremental compilation](https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript#incremental-compilation) like in the gulp example.

And my `tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
           "src/*": [
               "./src/*"
           ]
        }
    },
    "files": [
        "src/main.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to allow for aliasing of the src directory as `src/module_name` so resolutions work correctly for stuff like `import foo from 'src/la/ja'`. So if I'm in a deeply nested file, such as `src/something/other/foo.ts` and I want to import something from a utils folder in src, I can avoid messy paths `import bar from '../../../utils/bar'` and just do `from 'src/utils/bar'`.

Inside my `main.ts`, i'm trying to get:

```
import { a } from 'src/a'
```

To compile with the correct relative directory. With my current `tsconfig.json`, this resolves (definitions seem fine) and doesn't throw any linting errors, but when it compiles - it compiles as:

```
const a_1 = require("src/a");
```

instead of

```
const a_1 = require("./a");
```

So when trying to run it, it fails since `src/` is not found in `release/js/`. Is there any way to force typescript to compile to relative paths?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Nope, it's still an issue

Comment: Try this https://gist.github.com/rochapablo/3fc1186acc744407fffcf4aa34a689fe

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while setting up a dual-stack (js+ts) compiler with gulp, this package helped: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript-path-resolver